# php running calendar within two weeks

Tags: php

I have a calendar that shows the current month, which we use for scheduling. A request was made to have today's date in the middle, with two weeks of dates on either side.

Current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Running calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

//Get today's date
$date = time();

//Break date into separate values
$day = date('d',$date);
$month = date('m',$date);
$year = date('Y',$date);

//Generate first day of the month
$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

//Grab month name
$title = date('F',$first_day);

//Here you find out what day of the week the first day of the month falls on
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ;

//We then determine how many days are in the current month
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ;

switch($GLOBALS['day_of_week'])
{
case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
}

$currHour = date("H");

echo "<div id=container>";
echo "<table width=100% class=calendar>";
echo "<tr><th colspan=32 id=title>$title $year</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><th>Employee</th>";
$day_num=1;
while($day_num <= $days_in_month){
echo "<th align=center ";
if($day == $day_num){echo "id=day";}
echo ">$day_num</th>";
$day_num++;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What they would like to see:

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

I haven't had any luck getting the code figured out to display the past two weeks properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `for` loop and `DateTime` and came up with this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 14; $i > 0; $i--) {
  echo ' '. DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time())
    ->modify('-' . $i . ' days')
    ->format('d');
}

echo PHP_EOL;
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('d');
echo PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {
  echo ' '. DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time())
    ->modify('+' . $i . ' days')
    ->format('d');
}
```

Output:

```
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 01 02 03 04
05
 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Demo: https://eval.in/828059

You can change the [values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) in the `DateTime::format` to give more info, e.g. `->format('d/m')` could also print the month.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped greatly, I basically removed most of the code I originally posted and used the provided code for the entire process. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest option is probably the following:

```
    $period = new \DatePeriod(
                             new \DateTime('-14 days'),
                             \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'),
                             new \DateTime('+14 days')
                             );
    foreach ($period as $day) {
        print $day->format("d") . " | ";
    }
```

Output is:

> 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 |
>   05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

And if you had to do something to today while looping simply grab it with an equality check:

```
if($day == new \DateTime()){
   print "<span style='background-color:red;'>".$day->format("d") . "</span> | ";
}else{
   print $day->format("d") . " | ";
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, When I first looked I thought of DateInterval but looks like I needed DatePeriod like you used +1.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the way you calculate the start-date and optionally the number of days you want to display.

For the start date, just change this:

```
$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
```

to:

```
// Substract 14 days from the $date
$first_day = $date - (60 * 60 * 24 * 14);
```

And you need to change your `while` loop to start at this date and run 28 (?) times.

Comment: OK, got the start date, but when running the loop, the numbers continue past 30 days, stopping at 48

    `$day_num=date('d',$first_day);
    $count = 1;
    while($count <= 28){
    echo "<th align=center ";
    if($day == $day_num){echo "id=day";}
    echo ">$day_num</th>";
    $day_num++;
    $count++;
    }`